# how to use block replace common delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, block

A class:

In following method, I use blocks to replace common delegate. Is it ok? The block in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I use it replace common delegate, but if it run, I click the table cell and the code crashes.

```
typedef void (^Block)(NSString *id,NSString *cityName);
@interface WLCCityListViewController : WLCBaseSquareViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{   
    Block _block;
    id<commonDelegate>delegate;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil Block:(Block)block
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _block=block;
    }
    return self;
}        

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WLCMainViewCityListData *data=[[self citylists]objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    //    [self.delegate seleteCityID:[[data.cityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]  CityName:[[data.cityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
    NSString *a1 =[[data.cityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"];

    NSString *a2 =[[data.cityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    _block(a1,a2);    
}
```

B class:

```
@interface WLCMainViewController : WLCBaseSquareViewController
{
}
@implementation WLCMainViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    WLCCityListViewController *tableViewController = [[[WLCCityListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WLCCityListViewController" bundle:nil Block:^(NSString *id, NSString *cityName) {
        self.cityID=id;
        WLCMainViewModel *model=(WLCMainViewModel *)self.mainviewModel;
        model.cityID=id;
        [model sendRequest];
        [self.view startWaiting];
    }] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Crashes how? Can you provide the crash log?

Comment: error : address does not contain a section that point to a section in a object file  (thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0*0))

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad {
    WLCCityListViewController *tableViewController = [[[WLCCityListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WLCCityListViewController" bundle:nil Block:Block_copy(^(NSString *id, NSString *cityName) {
        self.cityID=id;
        WLCMainViewModel *model=(WLCMainViewModel *)self.mainviewModel;
        model.cityID=id;
        [model sendRequest];
        [self.view startWaiting];
    })] autorelease];
}    it works ok. just add "Block_copy",why?

Answer (score 0):

```
_block = block;
```

This line makes the crash. you just assign a block but doesn't keep it.DON'T USE retain,only use copy.
declare a copy property.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) Block _block;
```

and use setter. or just change you code like this.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil Block:  (Block)block
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    //_block=block;
    _block = block? [[block copy] autorelease]: nil;
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the block as a OC object.
 Generally if you need to keep the block, use Block_copy to do so and don't forget to Block_release it.
The problem of your code is that the block is autoreleased when you call it.